# The code cannot be compiled! Try to compile manually from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, unreal-engine4

I've already installed Visual Studio 2019 and UE4.23, but whenever I create a new C++ project it comes up with this error:

> The code cannot be compiled.

And when opened in VS to compile manually, it give MSB3075 error.

I've tried to reinstall and everything, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the message that UE4 gives:

```
> The project could not be compiled. Would you like to open it in Visual Studio?
```

Following is the error message that Visual studio gave:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB3075 The command 
""G:\Unreal Engine 4.23\UE_4.23\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" TestProjectEditor Win64 Development -Project="G:\UE4 Projects\TestProject\TestProject.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command. TestProject C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets
44
```

And the message that UE4 gives:

```
The project could not be compiled. Would you like to open it in Visual Studio?

Running G:/Unreal Engine 4.23/UE_4.23/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe Development Win64 -Project="G:/UE4 Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoHotReloadFromIDE
Creating makefile for MyProjectEditor (no existing makefile)
@progress push 5%
Parsing headers for MyProjectEditor
Running UnrealHeaderTool "G:\UE4 Projects\MyProject\MyProject.uproject" "G:\UE4 Projects\MyProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\MyProjectEditor\Development\MyProjectEditor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -installed
Reflection code generated for MyProjectEditor in 7.3832748 seconds
@progress pop
Using Visual Studio 2019 14.22.27905 toolchain (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905) and Windows 10.0.18362.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
Building 9 actions with 4 processes...
@progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 0%
@progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 11%
@progress 'Compiling C++ source code...' 22%
[2/9] Default.rc2
```

https://justpaste.it/5q9sc

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening VS with administrator privileges.